# How do I fix this error when trying to install another python library?

Tags: python

I have python 3.6 but it seems like it thinks I have 2.7 in the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 233, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 185, in main
    for name in ["pip._vendor", "distlib", "requests", "urllib3"]
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 565, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/compat/dictconfig.py", line 332, in configure
    del logging._handlerList[:]
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_handlerList'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `pip3` instead of `pip`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows and have more than one python version installed, find the location of the correct version and use

```
C:\path\to\python3\python.exe -m pip install name_of_library
```

If you are using Mac or Linux use

```
python3 -m pip install name_of_library
```

---

### Update

Thanks to @downshift for pointing out that the questioner has to be on a Mac. Nonetheless i decided to not to remove the solution for a windows machine because I think it may be useful for many people.

Comment: @downshift: You are right. Its  already late at night at my place, however I should have read more carefully. Nevertheless my answer should be correct :)

Comment: I agree :-) I just wanted to offer a little tip. I'll delete my comment. Have a good night.